# Change the way files are sorted on the Desktop with Applescript

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to write a simple Applescript to change the "Sort by" option in the Finder's Desktop View Options.

[image]

When trying to record the action in ScriptEditor, it does nothing. When recording the action with a folder open, it only registers the icon size...

Answer (score 0):

there can be several ways to do what you want automatically.
with Applescript in the Finder dictionary you can not reach the pop up Name to "show presentation options".
with **Automator** by creating a service and using "***File and Folders***" and "***get specified items***" and "***Set Folders View***" you can modify all options, and call the service whenever you want.

With Applescript it is necessary to collect UI Element AXSystemFloatingWindow, it is not very digestible, not always effective, but it exists.

Below is an example of applesscrcipt with an already open finder window.

```
set Name_loc to "Name"
set Name_loc1 to "None"

tell application "Finder"
    activate
    make Finder window
end tell

tell application "System Events" to tell process "Finder"
    set frontmost to true
    set wName to name of window 1
    if not (exists (first window whose (name is wName and subrole is "AXSystemFloatingWindow"))) then
        keystroke "j" using {command down}
        repeat
            if exists (first window whose (name is wName and subrole is "AXSystemFloatingWindow")) then exit repeat
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
    end if
    tell (first window whose (name is wName and subrole is "AXSystemFloatingWindow"))
        set thePopUp to pop up button 1
        click thePopUp
        click menu item Name_loc of menu 1 of thePopUp
        set thePopUp to pop up button 2
        click thePopUp
        click menu item Name_loc1 of menu 1 of thePopUp
        click button 1
        click button 2
    end tell
end tell

tell application "Finder"
    activate
    quit
end tell

delay 1
tell application "Finder" to activate
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using the latest version of macOS Mojave.

```
-- THE NUMBERS IN THE FOLLOWING RECORD VARIABLES ARE KEY CODE NUMBERS
property theSorting : {sortByName:18, sortByKind:19, sortByDateLastOpened:20, sortByDateAdded:21, sortByDateModified:23, sortBySize:22, sortByTags:26}

sortBy(theSorting's sortBySize) -- sort by size
-- sortBy(theSorting's sortByName) -- would be sort by name etc...

to sortBy(theNumber)
    tell application "Finder" to activate
    repeat until application "Finder" is frontmost
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    tell application "System Events"
        key code theNumber using {control down, option down, command down}
    end tell
end sortBy
```